# Cheapest way with public transport to travel to Ponza from Rome and back in one day?

Tags: public-transport, budget, rome, day-trips

There seem to be a variety of ways to get to Ponza from Rome. What is the cheapest option (so I don't care much about travel time) using public transport?

Doing research myself I am consistently ending up on Italian-only ferry sites which I have been trying to decode using Google translate, but I figured this might actually be common knowledge for Italian people, so am asking here.

My current *guess* would be that the cheapest option is going to Formia and taking the Laziomar ferry from there.

Comment: have you seen this : http://www.gillianslists.com/2014/06/how-to-get-to-ponza.html

Comment: @Max +1 you should make it an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gillian, Rome-based blogger, beach girl, ebook writer, information curator, traveler, coffee and cocktail drinker, has written the most perfect, and timely article](http://www.gillianslists.com/2014/06/how-to-get-to-ponza.html):

> I just got back from the ridiculously spectacular island of Ponza and I have so much to tell you. But, for now, while I sift through my pages and pages of notes and hundreds of photos, I will start with the basics and tell you the most important part; How to get to Ponza.
>
> I almost hate to write this post. This remarkable island in the middle of the Tyrrhenian Sea is not a secret or unknown, Romans have been coming here for centuries. Ponza, the largest of the Pontine islands, is not the easiest place in the world to get to. That is probably part of its magic.
>
> Ferries and hydrofoils depart from three different towns each of which are just over an hours train ride from Rome. Go to the Trenitalia website to book your train tickets in advance. The crossing takes about 2 and half hours. Hydrofoils are slightly faster, but are enclosed. I prefer to take the slower boat and sit on the top deck taking in the sea breeze and gorgeous views.
>
> **Terraccina**
>
> This option has the most steps, but when the Husband and the Teenager tried it on an early summer Friday evening everything worked perfectly. The last ferry of the day to Ponza leaves from here at 8:00pm.
>
> Train from Rome to Priverno/Fossanova the Bus or Taxi to Terracina Port
>
> Hourly Regionale train service between Roma Termini and Piverno/Fossanova (5 stops € 6.90)
>
> You can then take a taxi from the train station to the port or take two buses one first to the center of Terracina and then a second to the port. The buses are timed to coordinate with the train and ferry schedules.
>
> **Ferry/Hydrofoil from Terracina to Ponza**
>
> NLG has two hydrofoil departures daily between Terracina and Ponza. Tickets start at €20 one way/€30 round trip. Online booking is available.
>
> Laziomar has two crossings daily between Terracina and Ponza. Tickets are €10. Online booking is available.
>
> **Anzio**
>
> **Train from Rome to Anzio**
>
> Hourly Regionale train service between Roma Termini and Anzio (11 stops €3.90) You can take a taxi or a bus to the port from the Anzio train station.
>
> **Ferry/Hydrofoil from Anzio to Ponza**
>
> **Laziomar** has two crossings on weekdays and four on weekends between Anzio and Ponza. Tickets start at €24.
>
> **Vetor** In high season there are two to four crossings a day between Anzio and Ponza. Tickets start at €36. Online booking is available. Out of the season double check crossing days and times as they can be limited.
>
> **Formia**
>
> This is the easiest option.
>
> **Train from Rome to Formia/Gaeta**
>
> There are two train options that go directly from Roma Termini to Formia/Gaeta. You can book a Regionale  (9 stops €8.20) or an Intercity train (1 stop, assigned seats, AC and power outlets € 16.50.)
>
> **Ferry/Hydrofoil from Formia to Ponza**
>
> **Laziomar** has four crossings daily between Formia and Ponza. Tickets from  €16 for ferry €22 for hydrofoil.
>
> **Direct Transfers and Parking Information**
>
> If you prefer to drive from Rome to the ferry, each of the three departure points have paid parking lots. You can drive your car onto Ponza with you crossing with Laziomar. There are additional costs and booking requirements.
>
> **Golpho** Service located at the port in Formia can arrange long term parking, transfers and left luggage service.
>
> **Musella Viaggio** can arrange transfers from Rome or Naples to Terracina or Formia Ports starting from €130.

Comment: Se mi permettete me, I've added the content from the link; you can always roll it back :-)